# Maven not compiling against correct .class file

Tags: maven

We are having trouble with one of our Maven builds.

- Our project compiles correct locally (Windows) and on our local Jenkins.
- But on the CI Jenkins machine of our client, it fails.

The Java file `AbstractFehlteilelisteReport.java` refers to an Apache class named `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle`
which is listed in the `class-path` exactly one time with the correct version. We checked all of that.

But somehow the build manages to resolve a `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle.class` file of a different version, from a JAR unknown to us :-(, which does not have the `ALIGN_CENTER` field.

If it were a `pom.xml` config problem, the build should not succeed on our machines.

What we already checked:

- JDK versions same ... on all machines
- Maven versions same ... on all machines
- `settings.xml` same ... on all machines, except repo-urls
- Purged Maven `.m2` folder on our client's machine
- We also wrote a small script that takes the Maven `compile-path`/`class-path`, which is being used to compile the project, to see if there are other occurences of the mentioned class - but nothing found.

```
[INFO]---------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /var/apphome/162_cipbld/.jenkins/workspace/XXX/YYYYYY/Common/UtilServer/src/main/java/com/XXXX/util/server/report/creator/AbstractFehlteilelisteReport.java:[771,38]
    cannot find symbol: variable ALIGN_CENTER
```

We are out of clues ...

The POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>UtilProjects</groupId>
    <artifactId>UtilServer</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>UtilProjects</groupId>
        <artifactId>UtilProjectsParent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../UtilProjectsParent</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>Cp1252</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20190722</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>UtilProjects</groupId>
            <artifactId>Util</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.ibm.ws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.ws.runtime</artifactId>
            <version>9.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.rpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.xml.rpc-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <!-- Powermock hat ein Problem mit der 1.9.5 -->
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.was</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.j2ee.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient</artifactId>
            <version>9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpars</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi-xxxx-all</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-xxxx-all</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/poi-xxxx-all-3.9.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxx.corporateidentity</groupId>
            <artifactId>corporateidentity</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/PrintCorporateIdentity-1.6.0b.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxx.fontbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/fontbox-1.5.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxx.itext</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/itext-2.1.7.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxx.itext-hyph-xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext-hyph-xml</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/itext-hyph-xml.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxx.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/pdfbox-1.5.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>Commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.xxxx.commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The parent OM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>UtilProjects</groupId>
    <artifactId>UtilProjectsParent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>Global</groupId>
        <artifactId>GlobalRootPom</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../GlobalRootPom</relativePath>
    </parent>
    
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <!-- Java Version -->
        <java.version.source>1.8</java.version.source>
        <java.version.target>1.8</java.version.target>
        <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
        <!-- Source Files -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <!-- Java Build Plugin Versions -->
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>2.5.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-source-plugin.version>2.2.1</maven-source-plugin.version>
        <maven-javadoc-plugin.version>3.0.0</maven-javadoc-plugin.version>

        <!-- Dependency Versions -->
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.16.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
    
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptor>src/assembly/withSource.xml</descriptor>
                    <finalName>${pom.name}-${project.version}</finalName>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version.source}</source>
                    <target>${java.version.target}</target>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-source-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Grand-parent POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Global</groupId>
    <artifactId>GlobalRootPom</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven-javadoc-plugin.version>3.3.0</maven-javadoc-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-deploy</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-releases</id>
            <url>${releaseUrl}</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>maven-snapshots</id>
            <url>${snapshotUrl}</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

Settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<settings
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>maven-releases</id>
        </server>

        <server>
            <id>maven-snapshots</id>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>nexus-http-unblocker</id>
        </server>
        <server>
            <id>nexus</id>
        </server>
    </servers>

    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>nexus-http-unblocker</id>
            <mirrorOf>nexus</mirrorOf>
            <name></name>
            <url>XXX/nexus3/repository/REPO_GROUP</url>
            <blocked>false</blocked>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>nexus</id>
                    <url>XXX/nexus3/repository/REPO_GROUP</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>nexus</id>
                    <url>XXX/nexus3/repository/REPO_GROUP</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>deployment</id>
            <properties>
                <!-- for distributionManagement in GlobalRootPom -->
                <releaseUrl>XXX/nexus3/repository/REPO_GROUP/releases/</releaseUrl>
                <snapshotUrl>XXX/nexus3/repository/REPO_GROUP/snapshots/</snapshotUrl>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
        <activeProfile>deployment</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Comment: What are the operating systems of the different machines?

Comment: Have you tried `mvn -X ...` for debugging (the output is huge then but with much detailed information). Have you tried `mvn dependency:tree` on the project to see which dependencies pull in other (transitive) dependencies?

Comment: If you write „_`settings.xml` [...] except repo-urls_“ do you refer to `<localRepository>`, repo settings under `<servers>`, `<mirrors>`, `<proxies>` or `<profile><repositories>`? Can you add an anonymized `settings.xml` to your question? And, I do not see a `<repositories>` section in any of your POMs. Don't you use a repo manager like Artifactory, Nexus, etc. but just the default https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/?

Comment: RE: I added the settings.xml to the description

Comment: OSes: 
Successful Builds:   Windows 10, Docker Linux (Jenkins 2.271 Image), Red Hat Linux
Failed Builds:          Some Linux VM Jenkins 2.263.4

Comment: RE: yes we checked mvn dependency:tree

Comment: RE: yes we ran with -X

Comment: Have you checked the content of the Apache-Poi jars? Because using the scope “system” may not resolve this dependencies at all from any repository

Answer (score 0):

we found the problem !!!

the jre that we compiled with was NOT exactly the same.
in the folder jre/lib/ext of out client, there was a little extra jar poi-5.0.0.jar which found its ways into the boot-classbath. Shiiat.

We renamed it to *.jar.bak and voila !!!